# JavaScript поиск по json

Tags: jquery, phonegap, json, javascript, php

Здесь представлен код для поиска похожих значений. В браузере все работает отлично, но вот в мобильном браузере (PhoneGap) не работает поиск по русским символам, в чем может быть проблема.

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    value = $(this).val();
    Search(value,e);
})

function Search(val,evt) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        jSon = data;
    }).complete(function() {
        $.grep(jSon, function(elm) {
            myArray = elm.partner_name.match(RegExp(val +  String.fromCharCode(evt.which),'i'));
            if (myArray != null) {
                list = document.createElement('li');
                link = document.createElement('a');
                $(link).html(elm.partner_name).appendTo(list);
                $('ul').append(list);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: покажите серверный скрипт, скорее всего кодировка не совпадает

Comment: То есть не правильная кодировка того скрипта который отдает json, так ?